# Integration by parts - swapping the expressions

Tags: integration

I am having difficulty in integrating by parts the following integral:
$$
\int x^2 (e^{4x} + 3) \, dx
$$
Should I retain it as it or it would be better if I swap the expressions?

Regards and thanks

Comment: So I guess that you want to integrate
$$
\int x^2 e^{4x} \, dx$$ by parts, right? What did you try so far?

Comment: You want to differentiate the $x^2$, and antidifferentiate the $e^{4x}$, and then do it again. Try it!

Answer (score 1):

$$ \int x^2 (e^{4x} + 3) \, dx= \int( x^2e^{4x} + 3x^2) \, dx= 
\int x^2 e^{4x}dx+ \int 3x^2 dx $$ 
$$= \frac{e^{4x}{x^2}}{4} - \frac{1}{2} \int xe^{4x}dx + x^3 + c $$
 $$= \frac{e^{4x}{x^2}}{4} - \frac{1}{2} \bigg(\frac{e^{4x}x}{4} - \frac{1}{4}\int e^{4x} dx \bigg)+x^3+c$$

$$=\frac{e^{4x}{x^2}}{4} - \frac{e^{4x}x}{8} + \frac{e^{4x}}{32} +x^3+c
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int_{a}^{b}x^2 e^{4x}dx = \frac{e^{4x}{x^2}}{4}\Bigg|_{a}^{b} - \frac{1}{2} \int_{a}^{b}xe^{4x}dx = \frac{e^{4x}{x^2}}{4}|_{a}^{b} - \frac{1}{2} \bigg(\frac{e^{4x}x}{4}\Bigg|_{a}^{b} - \frac{1}{4}\int_{a}^{b}e^{4x} dx \bigg)
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can retain it as it & integrate by parts as follows
$$\int x^2(e^{4x}+3)dx=\int \underbrace{x^2}_{I}\underbrace{(e^{4x}+3)}_{II}\ dx$$
$$=x^2\int (e^{4x}+3)\ dx-\int 2x\cdot \left(\frac{e^{4x}}{4}+3x\right)dx$$
$$=x^2\left(\frac{e^{4x}}{4}+3x\right)-\frac12\int xe^{4x}dx-6\int x^2 dx$$
$$=\frac{x^2e^{4x}}{4}+3x^3-\frac12\left(x\frac{e^{4x}}{4}-\frac{e^{4x}}{16}\right)-6\frac{x^3}{3}$$
$$=x^3+\frac{e^{4x}}{32}(8x^2-4x+1)+C$$